# Converting list into lowercase

Tags: python, list, loops, lowercase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8OnG.png)
I want to convert the list into lower case but my output converts the last index object into a list in lower case. where am i going wrong? must be a lame question but i am super new to coding.

Comment: No screenshots please. See [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use list comprehensions.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```
    list = ['UPPER', 'UPPER', 'UPPER']
    list = [x.lower() for x in list]
    print(list)
    >>> ['upper', 'upper', 'upper']
```